# How can i get bearer token with email & password in ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authentication, bearer-token

I want to do authentication with office 365 in my mvc project and I need to create a bearer token.
How can i get bearer token with email & password in ASP.Net Core MVC

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call OFFICE365 API by using the graph api, I suggest you could follow this [article](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph).

After setting well, the asp.net core MVC will allow the user to login and then inside the controller, you could use tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync to get the accesstoken.